# consulta SQL para mostrar imagen por el ID

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-3

quisiera que me ayudaran a solucionar un problema que tengo en mi proyecto web, mi caso es que tengo dos productos dados de alta y quiero agregar imágenes en cada producto.
[image: esta es mi base de datos de los productos]

Como se puede ver en mi base de datos tengo dos imágenes diferentes (impresora.jpg y camara.jpg) pero al momento de mostrar las imagenes en la pagina web me muestra solo la ultima imagen guardada (camara.jpg)

Este es el producto de una impresora pero me muestra la imagen (camara.jpg)
[image: impresora]

Y este es el producto de una camara web y muestra la imagen (camara.jpg)
[image: camara]

Lo que quiero saber es si hay una sentencia sql para que en el producto de la impresora me muestre la imagen (impresora.jpg) que esta en mi base de datos.
Les dejo la sentencia sql que uso:

```html
$sql_last=mysqli_query($con,"select LAST_INSERT_ID(id_producto) as last from products order by id_producto desc limit 0,1");
 $rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_last);
 $id_producto=intval($rw['last']);
 $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where id_producto='$id_producto' limit 0,1");
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
 
 $rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
 $url_image=$rw['url_image'];
```

Espero que me ayuden!! no se si tengo que hacer una sentencia sql SELECT por el id.
Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: El codigo que pusiste siempre te va a retornar la ultima imagen en la base de datos.  Esta dentro de una funcion? o cual es el contexto.

Comment: No deberías coger el identificador por el último ID insertado. Cuando entras a la página de detalle de producto, la url debería tener un parámetro que identifica ese producto. Usa ese parámetro en vez de la última inserción en BBDD.

Comment: Ha muy bien, y cual seria la consulta adecuada para que me retorne las imágenes en sus respectivos productos dados de alta? No, el código no esta dentro de una función, solo quiero saber la consulta o la manera para que me muestre las imágenes dadas de alta en sus respectivos productos.

Comment: muchas gracias por sus ayudas!!! logre solventar mi problema!! ya retornan las imágenes según el ID!!

Answer (score 0):

Puede sonar a chapuza, pero yo si fuera tu cambiaría el nombre de la imagen para que sea el mismo que el del ID. Impresora.jpg siendo 1.jpg etc.

De esta manera siempre que busques el id, si le agregas .jpg al final siempre tendrás la imagen deseada.